# How to perform a nested When Otherwise in PySpark?

Tags: if-statement, pyspark, case-when

*Hi Everyone* , *Im trying to interpret this PowerBi Syntax & Transform it into Pyspark*

```
 if(UCS_Incidents[Intensity]="Very High",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="Very High","Red",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="High","Red",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="Medium","Orange","Yellow"))),

 if(UCS_Incidents[Intensity]="High",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="Very High","Red",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="High","Orange",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="Medium","Orange","Yellow"))),

 if(UCS_Incidents[Intensity]="Medium",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="Very High","Orange",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="High","Yellow",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="Medium","Yellow","Green"))),

 if(UCS_Incidents[Intensity]="Low",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="Very High","Yellow",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="High","Green",
 IF(UCS_Incidents[Severity]="Medium","Green","Green"))),

 ""))))
```

*And This is what i tried :*

```
 Intensities = df.withColumn(('Intensities',f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Very High') & (f.col('Severity') == 'Very High') , "Red").
                        otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Very High') & (f.col('Severity') == 'High') , "Red").
                        otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Very High') & (f.col('Severity') == 'Medium') , "Orange")
                        .otherwise('Yellow'))))
                        .otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'High') & (f.col('Severity') == 'Very High') , "Red").
                        otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'High') & (f.col('Severity') == 'High') , "Orange").
                        otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'High') & (f.col('Severity') == 'Medium') , "Orange")
                        .otherwise('Yellow'))))
                        .otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Medium') & (f.col('Severity') == 'Very High') , "Orange").
                        otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Medium') & (f.col('Severity') == 'High') , "Yellow").
                        otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Medium') & (f.col('Severity') == 'Medium') , "Yellow")
                        .otherwise('Green'))))
                        .otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Low') & (f.col('Severity') == 'Very High') , "Yellow").
                        otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Low') & (f.col('Severity') == 'High') , "Green").
                        otherwise(f.when((f.col('Intensity') == 'Low') & (f.col('Severity') == 'Medium') , "Green")
                        .otherwise('Green'))))

                        ).otherwise("")
```

*But , I got this Error :*

```
  A Tuple Object dosen't have an attribute Otherwise
```

*Any help would be much appreciated , thank you*

Comment: try to convert your embedded `if`s logic into an embedded SQL's case/when statement and then use `f.expr()` function to retrieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

just to give an example of what @jxc meant:
Assuming you already have a dataframe called df:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

Intensities = df.withColumn('Intensities', expr("CASE WHEN Intensity = 'Very High' AND Severity = 'Very High' THEN 'Red' WHEN .... ELSE ... END"))
```

I put "..." in as placeholder, but I think it makes the approach clear.